# How to modify parameter from knockout binding before displaying it?

Tags: razor, knockout.js

Apologies in advance - I'm very new to this.

The following (cropped) returns the desired parameter value. But how do I modify that value (e.g. apply some math to it) before displaying it?

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        <!-- ko text: values[i].value--><!-- /ko -->
    }
```

Attempts:

1. Assign to local variable, and then modify the variable.

   - Couldn't figure out whether assigning is even possible. This didn't work:

     ```
     @{
         var MTC = <!-- ko text: values[i].value--><!-- /ko -->;
     }
     ```
2. Write the math operation as a function in a script block. Pass the parameter value, return the modified value.

   - I am too new to even include attempted code here...

Comment: Did you read the [`text` binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html) documentation? it has a section called "Using functions and expressions to detemine text values" [sic], and a function is exactly what you need.

Comment: @HeyJude - Thank you. I read it but apparently did not understand it enough to connect the dots. Will try to implement and report results. Thanks again!

Comment: note you don't have to use `ko.pureComputed` as demonstrated there. You can completely omit it and stay with a simple function.

Comment: @HeyJude - Thank you for your input. I think I got stuck for the same reason as my response to the posted answer - the input values are so NaN that even parseFloat() returns NaN. I still don't know why, or how to fix that, but the answers provided here are sufficient for the posted question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use the text-binding to run any function,

so you could for example define a javascript object beforehand, that contains the desired function:

```
var helper = {
    returnModifiedValue:function(t){
       var _modified = parseFloat(t).toFixed(2);
       return _modified;
    }
}
```

and in your code:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        <!-- ko text: helper.returnModifiedValue(values[i].value)--><!-- /ko -->
    }
```

Comment: It looks like it's almost working (thank you!), but it's not recognizing my values (percentages and dollar amounts) as numbers (I get **NaN** back). 

However, if, instead of `parseFloat()`, I set `_modified` equal to simply `t`, it displays what looks like unformatted numbers (-5.5%→-5.5, $14.10→14.10). 

Should I be using something other than `parseFloat()`?

Thanks again for the help!